# Issue populating modal for Import Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a modal for User imports. The modal is working fine from the users index page and a button on said page, however i want to add a nav-bar link and open it from anywhere in the app.

I have asked and received an answer similar to this question, however now I'm dealing with custom controller methods and collections in my routes.rb, this is causing me problems when trying to pop this open anywhere in the app.

**here is my modal partial:**

```
## layouts/_import_modal.html.erb
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="userImport" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <%= form_tag import_users_path, multipart: true, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do %>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <h4>Select File To Import</h4>
            <div class="input-group">
            <label class="input-group-btn">
            <span class="btn btn-primary">
            Browse&hellip;<input type="file" style="display: none;" multiple>
            </span>
            </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <%= submit_tag "Import User List", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My controller Action:**

```
  def import
    User.import(params[:file].path)
    redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Users Added Successfully'

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

**My import.js.erb:**

```
$("#userImport").modal('show');
```

**My model methods:**

```
  def self.headers
    { "Email Address" => "email",
      "First Name" => "f_name",
      "Last Name" => "l_name",
      "Telephone" => "primary_tel"
    }
  end

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.parse(self.parse_headers(file), headers: true) do |rows|
      User.create! row.to_hash
    end
  end

  def self.parse_headers (file)
    File.open(file) { |f|
                  first_line = f.readline
                  self.headers.each { |k,v| first_line[k] &&= v }
                  first_line + f.read }
  end
```

Now this is the weirdest part of all.. when I click the link in the navbar the server output is as follows:

```
Started GET "/users/import" for ::1 at 2016-08-31 23:07:59 -0600
Processing by UsersController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"import"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."user_ident" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_ident", "import"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (14.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 41ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `role' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <p>
    2:   <strong>Role:</strong>
    3:   <%= @user.role.name %>
    4: </p>
    5:
    6: <p>

app/views/users/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__2032490711892636426_70270834135860'
  Rendering /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.text.erb
  Rendering /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb
  Rendered /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendering /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
  Rendered /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.text.erb (30.8ms)
DEPRECATION WARNING: #original_exception is deprecated. Use #cause instead. (called from status_code_with_paginate at /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/will_paginate-3.1.0/lib/will_paginate/railtie.rb:49)
```

> **EDIT # 1 - Adds User routes output**

```
import_users POST   /users/import(.:format)           users#import
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                  users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                  users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)              users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)         users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)              users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)              users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)              users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)              users#destroy
```

> **EDIT # 2 - Adds New link_to and Server Error Output**

```
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)



TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):

app/models/user.rb:68:in `initialize'
app/models/user.rb:68:in `open'
app/models/user.rb:68:in `parse_headers'
app/models/user.rb:62:in `import'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:82:in `import'
  Rendering /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb
  Rendering /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.text.erb
  Rendered /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.text.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendering /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb
  Rendered /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.text.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendering /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb
  Rendered /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.text.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/developer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.text.erb (45.3ms)

<li><%= link_to "Click Here", import_users_path, :method => :post, remote: true, :id => 'user-import', "data-toggle" => "modal", 'data-target' => '#userImport' %></li>
```

Comment: `@user` is `nil` app/views/users/show.html.erb

Comment: Make sure you are assigning `@user` in `show` action of  `users_controller`

Comment: @Deepak - thats the problem tho.. why is the link rendering a show response? this is supposed to open the modal.. the show pages all populate and appear just fine.

Comment: Unless you set the method in the link in your nav bar, it will default to a GET request and it will not match your POST import route - it is matching GET "/users/:id" i.e. users show. Try changing your import route to be GET

Comment: @mahi-man Please See Edit # 2 Im on the right track but still just a bit off.